# Mac-o-linker-error caused by specific part of code in xcode 9

Tags: xcode9, swift4

[Click here for code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipMCi.png)

Recently I have updated my `Xcode` to version 9.

I try to run my app on my `iPhone 7` (ios 11).

During compiling it shows `Mac-o-linker` and I found which specific part causes it can someone help me to resolve it.

If I comment that part it runs fine and error is in camera part.

Comment: Pls Click "Commented code causes the error" this to view the image

Comment: Please add the code here and explain the issue in more detail

Comment: hi avishek bhattacahrya I tried to use camera for my app,when i tried to test it in iphone below part of the code causes mac-o-linker error #if (!arch(x86_64))
            let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
            let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                                 kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160                      ]I have attached the complete code in above question take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change below line

```
let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
```

to this

```
let previewPixelType = settings.__availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
```